# tablelayout not visible in my custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-tablelayout

I have been trying to get some data to show up in my dialog.

In the dialog I have a checkbox and two buttons that show up, so I know it is loading my layout file.

I am not certain what else to do, so why would the background on my dialog be completely transparent, and more importantly, why can't I see anything in the two views I have experimented with?

Here is my entire layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/show_all_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Include books read" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/books_by_author_select_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Books" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/books_by_author_cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout> 
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/books_by_author_list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="0">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="textfield 1-1"></TextView>

      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
    </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried this with a `ListView` but the same results. Directly below the two buttons the dialog is transparent.

The `TableLayout` has nine children when it finishes being initialized, and since it wasn't showing up, I then added the `TableRow` in the xml above, originally that block wasn't there.

```
    this.mContext = context;
    setContentView(R.layout.books_by_author);

    final TableLayout view = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.books_by_author_list);
    for(int position = 0; position < list.size(); position++) {
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.books_by_author_list);

        // create a new TableRow
        TableRow row = new TableRow(mContext);

        // create a new TextView
        TextView t = new TextView(mContext);
        // set the text to "text xx"
        t.setText(list.get(position).mTitle);

        // create a CheckBox
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox(mContext);

        // add the TextView and the CheckBox to the new TableRow
        row.addView(t);
        row.addView(c);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
    view.invalidate();
```

I have tried this with a `ListView` and just using an `ArrayAdapter`, and I have created a custom adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` and `BaseAdapter`.

I have also explicitly set the background of the `ListView` and `TableLayout` to be Color.YELLOW, and tried setting other colors, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout doesn't work in many cases. Moreover, while running your app, TableLayout creates problem.

Always prefer using LinearLayout or FrameLayout.

Linearlayout can fit at any place where you are using TableLayout.

Comment: I am trying to show the data as a table, as that will probably be better than using a list.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** The problem was that the `LinearLayout` containing the buttons has `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content` for the `layout_height` attribute.